# ANSI PADDING defaults question

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have SQL Server 2008 SP2. I noticed that DBs by default have Properties | Options | Miscellaneous | ANSI Padding Enabled = FALSE.

However, [this BOL article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259201%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx) warns against setting it to off (no reason given). Further, [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187403.aspx) states this feature is going to be deprecated.

I have two questions:

1. What is the "problem" with having it off for current work (future deprecation aside)?
2. Why is it defaulted to FALSE when BOL says the default is ON, and should this setting therefore be changed?

Answer (score 2):

To your second point: I'm not quite sure why the default setting for you is OFF, when this article (SQL Server 2008) states that the default is ON:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187403.aspx

To your first point: if you don't want padded values, you can just set your columns to VARCHAR. Setting padding = OFF means you are effectively suppressing the difference (in this sense) between CHAR and VARCHAR columns.

Comment: The defaults is a mystery. Fortunately, I almost always use VARCHAR / NVARCHAR, so it doesn't affect me.